# Redis clears data itself..!

Tags: redis

I am using Redis since last 12 months without any issue, But from last 30 days unknowingly the database getting empty and we couldn't find any logs regarding this. Even it is flushing all the data out randomly after restoration.

We tried following steps to resolve this but **result was zero.**

1. We have checked redis logs
2. Monitored the redis using MONITOR command
3. We are trying to renaming the critical commands through config but redis is dump after the config change below is example command

   ```
   rename-command FLUSHDB e0cc96ad2eab73c2c347011806a76b73
   ```

We gone made without knowing anything. Helps are appreciated.

**Redis Version : 2.8.17**

**Running under Debian Linux**

Comment: Are you using RDB or AOF for persistence?

Comment: Hi @Eli we are using RDB for the persistence.

Comment: If you are renaming FLUSHDB, you'll also need to rename FLUSHALL, SLAVEOF, CONFIG and DEBUG. You can also use `INFO commandstats` to get an idea of which commands have been issued, if you weren't monitoring at the time. Check the RDB file itself is being fully written and successfully loaded on startup. Pasting your config and `INFO all` output might help us.

Comment: Switch to AOF. You'll get a full log of every write operation received against the server that way, and will be able to pinpoint exactly what happens immediately before the db is cleared.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for your reply but we are clueless to renaming the commands.

Comment: redis stopped responding when we are adding the rename command. Please help me to add these under config

Comment: Hi Everyone, Renaming the config clicks and now we are safe from other resources / hacks from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the command through config file will work in this case.

Same rename command you have to place inside the config file.

rename-command FLUSHDB e0cc96ad2eab73c2c347011806a76b73